Recursive traits for flattening multidimensional vectors
Suppose I we want to flatten vectors:
[0, 50, 100] -> [0, 50, 100]
[[0], [50, 50], 100] -> [0, 50, 50, 100]
[[[0]]] -> [0]

We can define a trait such as
pub trait FlattenVec<A> {
    fn flatten(self) -> Vec<A>;
}

And apply it to nested types,
impl<A, T> FlattenVec<A> for Vec<T>
where
    T: FlattenVec<A>,
    A: AtomicType
{
    fn flatten(self) -> Vec<A> {
        self.into_iter()
            .flat_map(|nested| nested.flatten().into_iter())
            .collect()
    }
}

where AtomicType is some trait implemented for types such as i32. Then, if we write the following base case:
impl<A> FlattenVec<A> for Vec<A>
where
    A: AtomicType,
{
    fn flatten(self) -> Vec<A> {
        self
    }
}

We get the following error:
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `vector::FlattenVec<_>` for type `Vec<_>`

However, if instead we replace <A> for a concrete type such as i32 or u32, the code compiles and functions as intended.
To me, it seems that there are no conflicting implementations whenever FlattenVec<A> is mutually exclusive from AtomicType. Does anyone know why this error occurs and how we might solve it to save ourselves from having to implement the trait for each atomic type?

This isn't going to be possible because the type system cannot (yet) do specialization or negative impls, which is necessary for a base case. The typical way to do this is at runtime with enums.
